# Django Data import from JSON file to DB not working with OneToOneFields

Tags: python, json, django

I'm currently working on an importer which lets me import a json file from a folder which i get from another server.
So far i can import all the regular fields of my model but the parts that are using OneToOneFields are not being imported. Instead i get this error message:

```
Something went wrong saving this Facility: Test Facility
Field 'id' expected a number but got {'PrimaryAddress': '1234 Test Avenue', 'SecondaryAddress': '', 'City': 'Testcity', 'RegionOrState': 'CA', 'PostalCode': '12345', 'Geolocation': ''}.
```

This is my code including the json i'm importing and the database model:

```
import os
import json
from data_import.models import Facility, FacilityAddress
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from datetime import datetime
from jsontest.settings import BASE_DIR, STATIC_URL


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def import_facility_from_file(self):
        print(BASE_DIR)
        data_folder = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'import_data', 'resources')

        for data_file in os.listdir(data_folder):
            with open(os.path.join(data_folder, data_file), encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
                data = json.loads(data_file.read())

                for key, data_object in data.items():
                    Name = data_object.get('Name', None)
                    IssuedNumber = data_object.get('IssuedNumber', None)
                    PrimaryAddress = data_object.get('PrimaryAddress', None)
                    SecondaryAddress = data_object.get('SecondaryAddress', None)
                    City = data_object.get('City', None)
                    RegionOrState = data_object.get('RegionOrState', None)
                    PostalCode = data_object.get('PostalCode', None)
                    Geolocation = data_object.get('Geolocation', None)

                    try:
                        facility, facility_created = Facility.objects.get_or_create(
                            Name=Name,
                            IssuedNumber=IssuedNumber,
                            
                        )
                        facility_address, address_created = FacilityAddress.objects.get_or_create(
                            PrimaryAddress=PrimaryAddress,
                            SecondaryAddress=SecondaryAddress,
                            City=City,
                            RegionOrState=RegionOrState,
                            PostalCode=PostalCode,
                            Geolocation=Geolocation,
                            AddressInfo=facility
                        )

                        if address_created:
                            facility_address.save()
                            display_format = "\Facility, {}, has been saved."
                            print(display_format.format(facility))
                    except Exception as ex:
                        print(str(ex))
                        msg = "\n\nSomething went wrong saving this Facility: {}\n{}".format(Name, str(ex))
                        print(msg)


    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        """
        Call the function to import data
        """
        self.import_facility_from_file()
```

```
class Facility(models.Model):
    UUID = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    admin_uid = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    AddressInfo = models.ForeignKey("FacilityAddress", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    IssuedNumber = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    mainimage = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    Capacity = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    Licensee = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    Email = models.EmailField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    AdministratorName = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    TelephoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    ClosedTimestamp = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    MostRecentLicenseTimestamp = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    InspectionInfo = models.OneToOneField(FacilityInspectionInfo, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    Complaints = models.OneToOneField(FacilityComplaints, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "facilities"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name

class FacilityAddress(models.Model):
    PrimaryAddress = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    SecondaryAddress = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    City = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    RegionOrState = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    PostalCode = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Geolocation = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    AddressInfo = models.ForeignKey(Facility, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "facility addresses"

    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.PrimaryAddress} {self.City}"
```

```
{"00016ed7be4d872aseddsf6f36bfsdfd647f3eb41cadedd2130bdfsdfsdf6fbbbf24c2f1a64d2cf34ac4e03aaa30309816f98a7389b2bb324a2":{"UUID":"00016ed7be4d872aseddsf6f36bfsdfd647f3eb41cadedd2130bdfsdfsdf6fbbbf24c2f1a64d2cf34ac4e03aaa30309816f98a7389b2bb324a2","Name":"SENIOR CARE","IssuedNumber":"123456","Licensee":"SENIOR CARE","Email":"test@dfjksdajfkljklsd.com","AdministratorName":"Tester","TelephoneNumber":"(123) 456-789101112","AddressInfo":{"PrimaryAddress":"123 Test Road","SecondaryAddress":"","City":"Testcity","RegionOrState":"TESTSTATE","PostalCode":"12345","Geolocation":"11.1111,-11.1111"},"Capacity":1,"MostRecentLicenseTimestamp":1234567891,"ClosedTimestamp":0,"InspectionInfo":{"ComplaintRelatedVisits":0,"InspectionRelatedVisits":0,"NumberOfVisits":0,"LastVisitTimestamp":0},"Complaints":{"ComplaintsTypeA":0,"ComplaintsTypeB":0,"SubstantiatedAllegations":0,"TotalAllegations":0}},
```

Does anyone know how i can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create both a `Facility` and a `FacilityAddress`, you need a `get_or_create` statement for both of them. Then, you keep a variable for the created/retrieved `FacilityAddress`, and you provide that to `Facility`.

Example:

```py
facility_address, address_created = FacilityAddress.objects.get_or_create(
    PrimaryAddress=PrimaryAddress,
    SecondaryAddress=SecondaryAddress,
    City=City,
    RegionOrState=RegionOrState,
    PostalCode=PostalCode,
    Geolocation=Geolocation
)
facility, facility_created = Facility.objects.get_or_create(
    Name=Name,
    IssuedNumber=IssuedNumber,
    AddressInfo=facility_address
)
```

This code creates the facility address if it does not exist, and provides the object representing that address to the second `get_or_create`.

Side note: `AddressInfo` should probably be a `ForiegnKey`, not a `OneToOneField`, unless it is impossible for two facilities to exist at the same address.

Comment: I made the changes accordingly and the importer does not give me any errors but it will create only one empty address field and all the facilities without an address field attached to them. Is there maybe something im missing on the save method that i need to change?

Comment: I updated my code above since i can't paste code in here.

Comment: I made some changes and now it is creating an address entry for each facility. But it is still not adding any data into the address fields so my guess is that because the address part is nested inside it's own object i need to make some modifications to "for key, data_object in data.items():" or the "PrimaryAddress = data_object.get('PrimaryAddress', None)" part? I can't seem to find any documentation on this unfortunately. Updated the code above again.

Comment: @Matthias Hmm, didn't notice that. Yeah, you probably need to do something like `PrimaryAddress = data_object["AddressInfo"]["PrimaryAddress"]` to get the data out of the sub-dictionary.